# Generating NaN when computing gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Environment info**

**Operating System:**
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6

**Tensorflow version:**
0.10.0rc0

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5.23

I'm running a model with temporal attention strategy (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02927). I use `tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example()` to compute the loss, and use adam gradient (lr:0.001) to minimize loss. The loss is not NaN, but gradients of some weigths became NaN values. If I use vanilla attention strategy, it won't have this NaN problem.

I even print out all hyperparameters, their values are real values until their gradients become NaN.

Hope someone can help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Partial Code**

```
attn_vec = tf.reduce_sum(attention_states * y, [2]) # initial attention weights
if step > 0:
    history = tf.pack(acc_sum)
    max_hist = tf.reduce_max(attn_vec, 1, keep_dims=True)
    cur_scores = tf.exp(attn_vec - max_hist) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp((history-max_hist)), 0) # reweight attention weights
else:
    cur_scores = tf.exp(attn_vec - tf.reduce_max(attn_vec, 1, keep_dims=True))
    m = cur_scores / tf.reduce_sum(cur_scores, 1, keep_dims=True) 
    acc_sum.append(attn_vec)
```

Comment: How are you initializing the weights? If you could provide some code it will be helpful

Comment: Maybe an even smaller learning rate?

Comment: I used xavier initializer, and smaller learning rate didn't help.